# Adding numbers to a string?

Tags: c#

I have strings that look like "01", "02". Is there an easy way that I can change the string into a number, add 1 and then change it back to a string so that these strings now look like "02", "03" etc. I'm not really good at C# as I just started and I have not had to get values before.

Comment: Do all your numbers have 0's in front or is that just an example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get from a string to an integer, you can youse `int.Parse()`:

```
int i = int.Parse("07");
```

To get back into a string with a specific format you can use `string.Format()`:

```
strings = string.Format("{0:00}",7);
```

The latter should give "07" if I understand http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-int/ correctly.

Comment: +1 This is correct. The "00" part of the format string indicates that you want 2 or more digits, padded left with 0 if needed to ensure 2 digits.

Comment: +1 this with the caveat of a preference for using TryParse instead of straight parse.

Comment: Actually, if you are turning only one number into a string, it's slightly more efficient to call the ToString instance method.

Comment: @phoog `ToString` would format it as `7` not as `07` which was requested.

Comment: @Anders Abel: not so. There is an overload that takes a string parameter (that is, 7.ToString("00") would return "07"). It requires both less typing and fewer instructions than calling string.Format.

Comment: @phoog I didn't know about that overload. One learns something new every day. Thanks :-)

Comment: It seems very few people know about that overload. But string.Format _calls_ that overload when presented with a format specifier such as "{0:00}", so it's easy to see both that ToString is more efficient and that it will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into a number using Convert.ToInt32(), add 1, and use ToString() to convert it back.

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(originalString);
number += 1;
string newString = number.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the integer

```
int i = int.Parse("07");
```

add to your integer

```
i = i + 1;
```

make a new string variable and assign it to the string value of that integer

```
string newstring = i.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry missed the format part :P  Read too fast! See response below :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AddStringAndInt(string strNumber, int intNumber)  
{
    //TODO: Add error handling here
    return string.Format("{0:00}", (int.TryParse(strNumber) + intNumber));
}
```

Comment: This function is garbage in its current form, `TryParse` takes an `out` parameter which holds the parsed value. And the return value of the TryParse (which is a boolean) will be what is inserted in the string.Format.

Answer (score 0):

```
static string StringsADD(string s1, string s2)
{
    int l1 = s1.Count();
    int l2 = s2.Count();

    int[] l3 = { l1, l2 };
    int minlength = l3.Min();
    int maxlength = l3.Max();
    int komsu = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlength; i++)
    {

        Int32 e1 = Convert.ToInt32(s1.PadLeft(maxlength, '0').ElementAt(maxlength - 1 - i).ToString());
        Int32 e2 = Convert.ToInt32(s2.PadLeft(maxlength, '0').ElementAt(maxlength - 1 - i).ToString());
        Int32 sum = e1 + e2 + komsu;
        if (sum >= 10)
        {
            sb.Append(sum - 10);
            komsu = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(sum);
            komsu = 0;
        }
        if (i == maxlength - 1 && komsu == 1)
        {
            sb.Append("1");
        }

    }

    return new string(sb.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

I needed to add huge numbers that are 1000 digit. The biggest number type in C# is double and it can only contain up to 39 digits. Here a code sample for adding very huge numbers treating them as strings.